# Is there anyway to sort this array of strings alphabetically?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, sorting

```
array_str = array('u', ['takeoff', 'airplane', 'rudder', 'propeller']) 
array_order = sorted(array_str) print(array_order)
```

I keep getting the same error: "TypeError: array item must be unicode character"
And I already tried to change it to unicode character.

Comment: Hello. What is this `array( ... )` in your code? Do you have `from something import array` somewhere in your code? Or maybe `def array(...):`?

Comment: That's not what `array` is for. Use a `list`, which doesn't even need the word. `list_str=['takeoff', 'airplane', 'rudder', 'propeller']`, `list_order=sorted(list_str)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since U r using python 3x Try the same logic without using array module. It worked ok for me without even using unicode chars

```
array_str =  ['takeoff', 'airplane', 'rudder', 'propeller'] 
array_order = sorted(array_str) 
print(array_order)
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually knew that it was possible to do it using lists, but I came across this error while using arrays and thought it was also possible to sort it alphabetically.